# What's a good algorithm to get all the posts and comments in a Facebook group?

Tags: python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

My ultimate goal is to get all the posts in a Facebook group along with their entire comment threads.

I'm currently using the `/group/feed` endpoint, but it is not maintained in an orderly fashion. Each post object has two time fields, `created_time` and `updated_time`. The first one as the name says is the time when the post was created. The latter however gets updated whenever some comment is added to the post.

This is how the current code looks like (pseudo-code):

```
def process_group(group):
    for post in posts:
        post_data = parse_data(post)
        comment_data = get_comments(post_data)
        save_to_database(post_data)

def get_comments(post):
    return comment_string

def main():
    while True:
        for group in groups:
            process_group(group)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The script runs in an infinite loop because I want to crawl ALL the posts *and* comments. Once the `for group in groups:` loop gets finished, the script starts from the first group and continues forward.

What I need is a clever way to avoid re-crawling posts and comments that have already been crawled. I tried something with [`since` and `until`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading) but [as per the Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/group/feed), they only apply on the `updated_time` field.

PS: I'm not asking anyone to write code; any helpful suggestions as to how to proceed with the algorithm would be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t think there’s much room for improvement, apart from storing the updated_time of the posts somewhere, so that next time you loop over all posts, you can at least determine for which ones you don’t need to request comments again. (And for those where you do, it might make sense to use since = post update time in the specific comment query then.)

Comment: I'm storing updated_time of each post in a database. But is there no way to avoid recrawling each posts?

Comment: Webhooks aren’t available for group feeds yet, so yes, that is currently the only way I think.

Comment: Can you post an answer describing the pseudo-code with the best algorithm you have in mind for this particular task? Seems I'll have to settle with this.